# How to configure Vite with index.html in public folder

Tags: reactjs, vite, bundler

In my React app that uses Vite, I want to put the `index.html` in a `public` folder. The structure looks like so:

```
root/
├── public/
│   └── index.html
├── index.js
└── vite.config.js
```

In `index.html` there is this line:

```html
<script type="module" src="../src/index.js"></script>
```

The Vite config looks like so:

```js
export default defineConfig(() => {
    return {
        define: {
            'process.env': {}
        },
        server: {
            port: '1112',
            strictPort: true
        },
        esbuild: {
            loader: 'jsx',
            include: /src\/.*\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: []
        },
        optimizeDeps: {
            esbuildOptions: {
                plugins: [
                    {
                        name: 'load-js-files-as-jsx',
                        setup(build) {
                            build.onLoad({ filter: /src\/.*\.js$/ }, (args) => ({
                                loader: 'jsx',
                                contents: fs.readFileSync(args.path, 'utf8')
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: { ...absolutePathAliases }
        },
        build: {
            rollupOptions: {
                input: {
                    main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
                },
            },
            outDir: 'build'
        },
        plugins: [react()]
    };
});
```

When I run the server and open the app in the browser I see a 404 error. Moving the `index.html` into the root, next to the Vite config, it works. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but in defineConfig we are including  publicDir: '../shared/public',

Comment: What would this config look like @PhilCowan?

Comment: Just put that on the object that you are returning I believe, but looking again at our code, our index.html file is not actually in our public directory either.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/#index-html-and-project-root

So it seems, that you should either move your index.html to the root folder or you can restructure your project so that you have an alternative root using e.g. `vite serve some/sub/dir`

From the docs:

> Specifying Alternative Root Running vite starts the dev server using
> the current working directory as root. You can specify an alternative
> root with vite serve some/sub/dir. Note that Vite will also resolve
> its config file (i.e. vite.config.js) inside the project root, so
> you'll need to move it if the root is changed.